# Webpack not reading my html navigation

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack, jsx

I'm creating a component in my webpack and I'm receiving this error:

ERROR in ./src/components/MainNav.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unterminated JSX contents (121:12)

```
  ReactDOM.render(
>    <MainNav/>,
               ^
 document.getElementById('MainNavigation'));
```

The error is saying I need to remove the comma after , but the comma certainly belongs there.  I'm thinking there is another syntax error in my html or I have elements that need to be modified in order to be read by my webpack. Not sure what's wrong????

Below is my component:

```
        export class MainNav extends React.Component {
          render() {
            return (
            <div>   


            <nav className="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
          <div className="container-fluid">
        //     Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display 
            <div className="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle 
collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-
collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span className="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify">
</span>

              </button>
              <a className="navbar-brand" href="#"><img 
src="img/transport-explorer-logo-white.png"/></a>
            </div>

        //     Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for 
toggling 
            <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-
navbar-collapse-1">


              <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li className="dropdown navspan">
                  <a href="#" className="" data-toggle="dropdown" 
role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span  
className="icon glyphicon glyphicon-cog" style="font-size:20px;">
</span></a>
                  <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                     <li className="nav-pills">
                         <a href="tools.php">
                             <span className="icon glyphicon 
glyphicon-wrench"></span> Tools
                         </a>
                     </li>
                     <li role="separator" className="divider"></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li className="dropdown profile-box">
                  <a href="#" className="dropdown-toggle" data-
toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-
expanded="false">
                    <span> Welcome Back: </span>
                  <img src="img/profile-placeholder.jpg" 
className="img-circle"/>

                  </a>
                  <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a>
                    User ID: </a></li>
                    <li><a>User:  </a></li>
                          <li><a>Company ID: </a></li>
                          <li><a>Company: </a></li>
                    <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>  
          </div>  
        </nav>

            <div id="wrapper">

                // Sidebar 
                <div id="sidebar-wrapper" className="">
                    <ul className="sidebar-nav li-move phpinclude">
                      <li className="nav-pills"><a href="/index.php">
<span className="icon glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span>  
Shipments<span className="sr-only"></span></a></li>

                        <li className="nav-pills"><a href="/your-
docs.php"><span className="icon glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate">
</span>All Documents</a></li>
                      <li className="nav-pills" role="presentation"><a href="/all-messages.php"><span className="icon glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>  All Messages <span className="badge">33</span> </a></li>
                      <li className="nav-pills"><a href="/reports.php"><span className="icon glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase"></span>  Reports</a></li>
                      <li className="nav-pills"><a href="/dashboard.php"><span className="icon glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></span> Dashboard</a></li>
                      <li className="nav-pills"><a href="/users.php"><span className="icon glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>  Users</a></li>

                      <li className="nav-pills"><a href="/invoicing.php"><span className="icon glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></span>Invoicing & Statements</a></li>
                      <li className="nav-pills"><a href="/status-key.php"><span className="icon glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-lamp"></span> Status Key</a></li>
                      <li className="nav-pills"><a href="/wittwer-contacts.php"><span className="icon glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span> Wittwer Contacts</a></li>
                      <li className="nav-pills"><a href="/warehouse.php"><span className="icon glyphicon glyphicon-oil"></span>  Warehouse</a></li>
                      <li className="nav-pills"><a href="#"><span className="icon glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>Log Out</a></li>
                      <li>
                      <div id="spinnerWrapper"> 
                          <div className="spinner">
                              <div className="bounce1"></div>
                              <div className="bounce2"></div>
                              <div className="bounce3"></div>
                          </div>
                      </div>  
                      </li>


                  </ul>


              </div>
               //  #sidebar-wrapper 

                // Page Content 

          <div id="page-content-wrapper">


            <div className="col-sm-12 toggle-row">
                  <a href="#menu-toggle" className="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" id="menu-toggle"></a>
            </div>



             <div className="clearfix"></div>




            </div>  
           );
          }
         }


        ReactDOM.render(
          <MainNav/>,
          document.getElementById('MainNavigation')
        );
```

Comment: That HTML is a mess. Paste it here http://fixmyhtml.com/ , then wrap all the result in a <div></div> tag, and then try again. Your HTML may change a bit but at least it should work.

Comment: I'll have to start using the fixmyhtml.com tool in these situations.  Pretty awesome tool!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When pasted the `MainNav` code into Visual Studio Code I received some errors indicating there was missing closing `</div>` tags and unterminated string literal for `className` and `href` attribute values. I added two `</div>` at the very end of the component render HTML as well as remove line breaks from attribute string values and it was able to render successfully. I also had to remove a `style` attribute, but that could simply be the way CodeSandbox renders React.

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/4RwN1N5V0) showing the component rendering successfully (without styles).

Here is the full code that I was able to get to render:

```
export class MainNav extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <nav className="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
          <div className="container-fluid">
            // Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display
            <div className="navbar-header">
              <button
                type="button"
                className="navbar-toggle collapsed"
                data-toggle="collapse"
                data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
                aria-expanded="false"
              >
                <span className="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify" />
              </button>
              <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="img/transport-explorer-logo-white.png" />
              </a>
            </div>
            // Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling
            <div
              className="collapse navbar-collapse"
              id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"
            >
              <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li className="dropdown navspan">
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    className=""
                    data-toggle="dropdown"
                    role="button"
                    aria-haspopup="true"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                  >
                    <span className="icon glyphicon glyphicon-cog" />
                  </a>
                  <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                    <li className="nav-pills">
                      <a href="tools.php">
                        <span className="icon glyphicon glyphicon-wrench" />{' '}
                        Tools
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="separator" className="divider" />
                  </ul>
                </li>

                <li className="dropdown profile-box">
                  <a
                    href="#"
                    className="dropdown-toggle"
                    data-
                    toggle="dropdown"
                    role="button"
                    aria-haspopup="true"
                    aria-
                    expanded="false"
                  >
                    <span> Welcome Back: </span>
                    <img
                      src="img/profile-placeholder.jpg"
                      className="img-circle"
                    />
                  </a>
                  <ul className="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                      <a>User ID: </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a>User: </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a>Company ID: </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a>Company: </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>

        <div id="wrapper">
          // Sidebar
          <div id="sidebar-wrapper" className="">
            <ul className="sidebar-nav li-move phpinclude">
              <li className="nav-pills">
                <a href="/index.php">
                  <span className="icon glyphicon glyphicon-transfer" />
                  Shipments<span className="sr-only" />
                </a>
              </li>

              <li className="nav-pills">
                <a href="/your-docs.php">
                  <span className="icon glyphicon glyphicon-duplicate" />All
                  Documents
                </a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-pills" role="presentation">
                <a href="/all-messages.php">
                  <span className="icon glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" /> All
                  Messages <span className="badge">33</span>{' '}
                </a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-pills">
                <a href="/reports.php">
                  <span className="icon glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase" />{' '}
                  Reports
                </a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-pills">
                <a href="/dashboard.php">
                  <span className="icon glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard" />{' '}
                  Dashboard
                </a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-pills">
                <a href="/users.php">
                  <span className="icon glyphicon glyphicon-user" /> Users
                </a>
              </li>

              <li className="nav-pills">
                <a href="/invoicing.php">
                  <span className="icon glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card" />Invoicing
                  & Statements
                </a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-pills">
                <a href="/status-key.php">
                  <span className="icon glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-lamp" />{' '}
                  Status Key
                </a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-pills">
                <a href="/wittwer-contacts.php">
                  <span className="icon glyphicon glyphicon-globe" /> Wittwer
                  Contacts
                </a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-pills">
                <a href="/warehouse.php">
                  <span className="icon glyphicon glyphicon-oil" /> Warehouse
                </a>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-pills">
                <a href="#">
                  <span className="icon glyphicon glyphicon-log-out" />Log Out
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div id="spinnerWrapper">
                  <div className="spinner">
                    <div className="bounce1" />
                    <div className="bounce2" />
                    <div className="bounce3" />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          // #sidebar-wrapper // Page Content
          <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div className="col-sm-12 toggle-row">
              <a
                href="#menu-toggle"
                className="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"
                id="menu-toggle"
              />
            </div>

            <div className="clearfix" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <MainNav />,
    document.getElementById('MainNavigation')
);
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Your script worked!  Thank you for reviewing the code!

Comment: Glad to help! Mark the solution that helped you resolve your issue. Thanks!